# how to use joblib with scikitlearn to crossvalidate in parallel

Tags: python, scikit-learn, joblib

I am trying to execute cross validation folds in parallel with the joblib library in python.

I have the following sample code:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix, f1_score
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC

iris = datasets.load_iris()
X, Y = iris.data, iris.target

skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5)

#clf = svm.LinearSVC()
clf = svm.SVC(kernel='rbf')
#clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear')

f1_list = []

for train_index, test_index in skf.split(X, Y):
    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = Y[train_index], Y[test_index]
    clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
    Y_predict = clf.predict(X_test)
    f1 = f1_score(y_test, Y_predict, average='weighted')
    print(f1)
    conf_mat = confusion_matrix(y_test, Y_predict)
    print(conf_mat)
    f1_list.append(f1)
print(f1_list)
```

I would like to execute the for loop in parallel to obtain accuracy scores in parallel for each of the folds.

I believe the joblib library has to be used in the following way:

```
from math import sqrt
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
def producer():
     for i in range(6):
        print('Produced %s' % i)
        yield i
out = Parallel(n_jobs=2, verbose=100, pre_dispatch='1.5*n_jobs')(
                delayed(sqrt)(i) for i in producer())
```

any suggestions on how to accomplish the parallel task integration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `Parallel` constructor you use the `delayed` argument to designate the function you want to run in parallel. `delayed` returns a new function that wraps your function. You can then call the newly wrapped function with arguments that'll be passed to your original function.

In your example, the `sqrt` function is being wrapped by `delayed` and is then being sent `i` from a `range(6)` in parallel.

What we need to do is pass `delayed` a function that can train on a chunk of data and then pass that newly wrapped function the indices for the kfold split. Here's an example of doing that:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix, f1_score
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

iris = datasets.load_iris()
X, Y = iris.data, iris.target

skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5)
clf = svm.SVC(kernel='rbf')

def train(train_index, test_index):
    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = Y[train_index], Y[test_index]

    clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
    Y_predict = clf.predict(X_test)

    f1 = f1_score(y_test, Y_predict, average='weighted')
    conf_mat = confusion_matrix(y_test, Y_predict)

    return dict(f1=f1, conf_mat=conf_mat)


out = Parallel(n_jobs=2, verbose=100, pre_dispatch='1.5*n_jobs')(
    delayed(train)(train_index, test_index) for train_index, test_index in skf.split(X, Y))

f1_scores = [d['f1'] for d in out]
conf_mats = [d['conf_mat'] for d in out]

print('f1_scores:', f1_scores)
print('confusion matrices:', conf_mats)
```

Out:

```
f1_scores: [0.9665831244778613, 1.0, 0.9665831244778613, 0.9665831244778613, 1.0]
confusion matrices: [array([[10,  0,  0],
       [ 0, 10,  0],
       [ 0,  1,  9]], dtype=int64), array([[10,  0,  0],
       [ 0, 10,  0],
       [ 0,  0, 10]], dtype=int64), array([[10,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  9,  1],
       [ 0,  0, 10]], dtype=int64), array([[10,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  9,  1],
       [ 0,  0, 10]], dtype=int64), array([[10,  0,  0],
       [ 0, 10,  0],
       [ 0,  0, 10]], dtype=int64)]
```

`out` contains the returned metrics from the `train` function, so we can just split out the f1 scores and confusion matrices separately if we need to.

Comment: thanks a lot. Just wanted to ask what is the relationship between fold and parallel processes for examples if I have 5, 10, 15 folds how are they assigned to X number of processors (1, 2, 4, etc)

Comment: The `n_jobs` argument will dictate how many processor cores will be used. A value of -1 will use all cores available. Each fold will be put into a task queue to be picked up by a processor. So if you have 4 cores and 10 folds then 4 folds will be mapped to 4 cores and the remaining folds will wait for the next available core.